# Idiomatic way to exit ksh while loop

Tags: shell, while-loop, ksh, shell-trap

I've the following 5 second timer which prints an asterisk for each second.

```
timer () {
  i=1
  trap 'i=5' INT

  while [[ $i -le 5 ]]; do
    sleep 1
    printf "*"
    ((i+=1))
  done
}
```

Somehow the trap chunk seems a little hackish and I wonder if there's a more correct way to interrupt the entire loop (not just the current sleep cycle). I've tried:

```
trap 'print "foo"' INT
```

at various locations inside and outside the function, but as I alluded to before, that just interrupts the current sleep cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but what's wrong with:

```
timer() {
  i=0
  while (( ++i <= 5 )); do
    sleep 1
    printf '*'
  done
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think you addressed the trap part of my question. Regardless of how I perform the loop, I'm using trap to break out of the loop (but not the surrounding script, which is not shown here for simplicity). However your loop suggestion looks better than mine.

Comment: Hi, @amorphousone! If you need to set i to 5 when you receive sigint, you're already using the right code (but I doubt you really need this). If you need to break the loop earlier (i.e. for some reason before the while condition evaluates false), you need to use the break command.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm aware of break, but the break condition would still rely on user input (ctl-c). How would I keep a loop going while reading for user input in the background? (I've googled a lot for that).

Comment: Hi @amorphousone, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "rely on user input). As far as your second question is concerned, you could run the loop in background and read user input in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

function timer {

    trap "break" INT

    i=0
    while (( ++i <= 5 )); do
        sleep 1
        printf '*'
    done
}

echo "Starting timer"
timer

echo "Exited timer"
echo "Doing other stuff...."
```

and this in ksh (note the different location of the trap statement):

```
#!/bin/ksh

function timer {

    trap "break" INT

    i=0
    while (( ++i <= 5 )); do
        sleep 1
        printf '*'
    done
}

echo "Starting timer"
timer

echo "Exited timer"
echo "Doing other stuff...."
```